# How to add archassault repository to arch linux

Tags: linux, archlinux

I would like to add the archassault repository to my pacman.conf in vanilla arch linux file so that I can get the packages from archassault. Please show me what this looks like / how this is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to edit /etc/pacman.conf
and add the following information to it.

[archassault]

Server = http://repo.archassault.org/archassault/$repo/os/$arch

Afterwards, run the following sequence in a terminal. You have to be root for running these commands.

```
pacman-key -r CC1D2606
pacman-key --lsign CC1D2606
pacman -Sy --noconfirm archassault-keyring archassault-mirrorlist
```

Source: [this link](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/anexile/archlinux-assault/dockerfile/)

EDIT: you can then add the following line to your /etc/pacman.conf and replace the above location for archassault.

```
Include = /etc/pacman.d/archassault-mirrorlist
```

archassault-mirrorlist will allow you to choose a mirror closer to your location.